# Server fails to save or retrieve data and crashes app in python flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I first wrote the following code, which seemed to work:

[Full code](https://github.com/NezaVizintin/Guess_the_number_game)

Then I started to incorporate a password input field and kept getting an "Internal Server Error" whenever I tried putting in an existing user. When I used debugger it seems to fail when the program tries to retrieve information from the database but the errors seem to indicate it's failing to save data properly. The Flask server log says many things but more notably:

- ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
- sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email
- sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email
  [SQL: INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, number_secret) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
  [parameters: ('Brincelj', 'brinko.muc@maw.com', 'bk', None)]
  (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

Then I tried a solution that I found it works but I can not figure out why. Why does "try" and "except" not work?

Here is the code that **stopped working**:

```python
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    # gets data from form
    name = request.form.get("user-name")
    email = request.form.get("user-email")
    password = request.form.get("user-password")

    try: # tries to save the data in to the database as a new user - if the email already exists this will fail
        user = User(name=name, email=email, password=password)  # creates a User object
        user.save() # saves the user object into the database
    except: # if the user exists it creates that user as a a User object
        user = database.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user.number_secret: # if the user is new and doesn't have a secret number it creates one and saves it
        user.number_secret = number_secret_generate()
        user.save()

    response = make_response(redirect(url_for("index"))) # creates response that will redirect to the index function (refreshes the site)
    response.set_cookie("email", email) # sets cookie with the new email (if id doesn't exist yet) or saves the existig email in to a cookie to recognise the user

    return response
```

And here is the solution that does work (for now):

```python
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    # gets data from form
    name = request.form.get("user-name")
    email = request.form.get("user-email")

    user = database.query(User).filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user:
        # create a User object
        user = User(name=name, email=email)
        user.save()

    if not user.number_secret:
        user.number_secret = number_secret_generate()
        user.save()


    response = make_response(redirect(url_for("index"))) # creates response that will redirect to the index function (refreshes the site)
    response.set_cookie("email", email) # sets cookie with the new email (if id doesn't exist yet) or saves the existig email in to a cookie to recognise the user

    return response
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas and explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ this .save() syntax and can't find it in the sqlalchemy docs. Have you tried instead using the following syntax inside your try statement?

```
try: # tries to save the data in to the database as a new user - if the email already exists this will fail
    user = User(name=name, email=email, password=password)  # creates a User object
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```